# Unable to read json file from a .js script within ionic framework

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I have been trying to simply read a json file within a .js script in an ionic framework. My repository file structure is as per the following:

```
- public/...
- resources/...
- src/
  - components/...
  - pages/
     - Tab1.css
     - Tab1.tsx
  - utils
     - configs/config.json
     - utils.js
     - require.js
```

When I debug, I load an object from utils.js called by Tab1.tsx. The debugger successfully goes into the utils.js and calls "read_json" function as part of object creation, which looks like this:

```
export function read_json(){
    let json_data = fetch('./configs/config.json')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => console.log(json));
    console.log(json_data)
}
```

I get the following result: `Promise {[[PromiseState]]: 'pending', [[PromiseResult]]: undefined}`. I tried using the "await" function and the result was the same. I also tried using the require('./configs/config.json'), but then got error message `Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: require is not defined` despite having a require.js in my structure.

When I was loading the json outside of ionic framework, I did not have this issue. Could someone help?

Comment: What is the ionic framework version?

Answer (score 0):

This returns a promise that resolves as a Response object

> ```
> fetch('./configs/config.json')
> ```

---

This returns a promise that resolves as the result of parsing the JSON from the response body

> ```
> .then((response) => response.json())
> ```

---

This logs the JavaScript object/array/other value that you get from parsing the JSON (it doesn't log JSON, you parsed in in the previous step!) and then returns a promise that resolves as the return value of `console.log(...)` which is `undefined` and **not what you want**

> ```
> .then((json) => console.log(json));
> ```

Using `then` to do this you would want:

```
then( (value) => {
    console.log(value);
    return value;
});
```

---

Then you log the promise object:

> ```
> console.log(json_data)
> ```

---

> I tried using the "await" function

Your attempt to use it probably failed because of `console.log` returning `undefined` as mentioned above.

`await` is a keyword, not a function. Using it to handle **all** your promises instead of mixing it with `then` makes life much easier.

```js
const response = await fetch('./configs/config.json');
const value = await response.json();
console.log(value);
```

---

This all assumes that your URL is right. Generally the contents of `src` doesn't contain data served by a web server and you'd want to store the ``` .json`` file under ``` public`.

---

> then got error message Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: require is not defined despite having a require.js in my structure

You are using ECMAScript modules (using `import/export`) not CommonJS modules (which are Node.js' default module format and which work with a function named `require`) and also not AMD modules (which are what Require.JS uses, and which also use a function named `require` but not one that is compatible with CommonJS modules).

Answer (score 0):

You should return the value. Use this code

```
      export async function read_json(){
                let json_data =await fetch('./configs/config.json')
                    .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.json());
                   return response.json();
})
                console.log(json_data);
               return json_data;    
        }
```